# Is there a shorthand to assign window[functionName] = functionName many times?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I've got

```
window.getTask = getTask 
window.postTask = postTask
window.logIn = logIn
```

and I'm looking for a shorthand way to do this.  Something like `window[name] = [postTask, getTask, logIn]`  Does anything like that exist using modern javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to do something like this:

```
Object.assign(window, {
    getTask,
    postTask,
    logIn,
    // ... and so on
});
```